# Qualified for iOS4

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode, app-store

I just submitted an app to the App Store for the first time. During my build I set the deployment target to iOS 4.2. When using the Application Loader I was asked if the binary was "tested and qualified" for iOS4. I chose NO.

Generally speaking I'm wondering what exactly this question is for.

1. If you say YES does it mean your app is ready for all iOS versions 4.0 and above?
2. Do you get some sort of special promotion if your app does qualify?
3. Since I answered NO, does that increase my risk of not getting my accepted?
4. By choosing NO does that limit my apps distribution in any way?

All information concerning this subject welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: As you set the deployment target to 4.2, this already implies it works on iOS 4.2 and above. Last time I submitted an app was about a month ago or so. Don't remember seeing the question. Apple has sometimes asked this around the time of a major revision. I think it mainly shows up in the little requirements paragraph on the app's page in the App Store.